# Jboss wildfly server deploys the application but is unable to launch it even on localhost

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-11

We have an application packaged as war and deployed using the admin ui of jboss wildfly 11. The startup runs fine and gives the below message saying the server started up successfully.

```
00:42:35,046 INFO  [c.c.ffvc.FFlyVSA] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) Started FFlyVSA in 
38.067 seconds (JVM running for 86.783)
00:42:35,058 INFO  [com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient] (DiscoveryClient- 
InstanceInfoReplicator-0) DiscoveryClient_application/localhost:application:8090 - registration 
status: 204
00:42:35,178 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool 
 -- 64) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP4  for context ''
00:42:45,839 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYUT0021: 
Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
00:42:45,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "my- 
application.war" (runtime-name : "my-application.war")
00:42:45,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
00:42:46,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface 
listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
00:42:46,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening 
on http://0.0.0.0:9990
00:42:46,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final 
(WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 97630ms - Started 531 of 759 services (359 services are 
lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

However there is nothing running on the port 8090 on doing a netstat for that port. Also i'm unable to launch the application even on localhost.

**Note: started jboss using**

```
standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/my-application` ?

Comment: Yes tried that. Its launched on 8090. But there's nothing running on 8090.

Comment: Wildfly by default uses port 8080, not 8090. Did you override ports on standalone.xml?

Comment: The spring boot application has server.port set as 8090. The logs say the application started on 8090. We are running them as micro-services.

Comment: Considering there is no issue on the logs, go to http://localhost:9990/console/index.html ie. `Administration Console` > Deployments > click on the deployment, and the Context Root. This will access the deployment url.

Comment: You need to configure WildFly to listen on port 8090. WildFly doesn't know anything about Spring or Spring boot.